# The best way to use Android ORM Room?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, orm

I created a specific application to calculate wood measurements and I wanted to save the data in the smartphone ***AND*** on **an SD Card** (Recovery Save). In my case, I would use a database with an ORM.

I see the docs of many ORM (Room, GrennDao, OrmLite) but I'm not sure if my way of using the ORM is very appropriate because I want an 2 storage of the data one inside and one on an SD card.I have already tried to save Data with *Android Room ORM but the storage is only inside the app and I can't access to it.*

I want to know if my way of using the ORM is appropriate in my case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want isn't a matter of ORM layers.  What you want is a backup solution.  You can achieve the same thing more easily by just having an alarm copy the db file to the SD card once per day.

Comment: The problem is the ORM (Room) because I can't access to the DB created to make an copy on the SD Card. I tried to change de location of the DB but It doesn't worked.

Comment: Problem is fixed ! Thanks